# JSON Export Function

Tags: php, json, function, redirect, export

I have this little situation. I created a function that should let me export some arrays in a JSON format.

This is my code so far:

```
function export( $option_values ) {
$json = json_encode( $option_values );
$filename= '_' . date('Y-m-d_h.i.s', time());
$filename= '_WP-' . get_bloginfo('version');
$filename= '.json';
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'" );
header( 'Content-type: text/json');
header( 'Content-Length: ' . mb_strlen( $json ) );
header( 'Connection: close');
```

I get this error message:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent.

How can I complete this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you are outputting something. This can be intentional (with statements like `echo`, `print`, etc.), or unintentional by loading a php-script with an extra linefeed after the closing PHP-tag (`?>`).

Remove the output and you are good to go.

Comment: I deleted all the echos, but I still get the error.

Comment: @FilipRus The above is the guideline to fix it. The only other thing you can do is, is to call the script completely separate from any other code (in a separate file via a direct call to that file).